# Adding/changing ID3 tags to media files with "artist - title" format

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, file-system, boost

This code puts or changes ID3 tags to media files based on their file names. It assumes the files are in this format:

> ```
> morbid angel - maze of torment.mp3
> ```

The resulting tag would be:

> ```
> Artist: morbid angel
>
> Title: maze of torment
> ```

I use [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/) to iterate through the directory and [taglib](https://taglib.github.io/) to manipulate the tags.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#define TAGLIB_STATIC
#include <taglib/fileref.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace TagLib;

void changeTag(const path& p) {
    std::string filename = p.filename().string();
    FileRef file(p.string().c_str());
    std::string artist = filename.substr(0,filename.find(" -"));
    Tag* t = file.tag();
    t->setArtist(artist);
    t->setTitle(filename.substr(artist.size()+3, filename.size()-artist.size()-7));
    file.save();
    std::cout << t->artist() << " - " << t->title() << " saved" << '\n';
}

void extractFiles(const std::string& p) {
    std::vector<path> files;
    std::vector<std::string> errors; // for files that might cause errors
    try {
        path filepath = p;
        for (auto& i : directory_iterator(filepath)) {
            changeTag(i.path());
        }
    } catch(const filesystem_error& e) {
        errors.push_back(e.what()); // output later after all files have been processed
    }
    if (errors.size() > 0) {
        std::cout << "Some operations failed with errors:" << '\n';
        for (auto& i : errors) {
            std::cout << i << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string dir;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Directory: Enter 'x' to close: ";
        std::cin >> dir;
        if (dir == "x") {
            break;
        }
        extractFiles(dir);
    }
}
```

How can I improve this code? How can I make this faster, cleaner and better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things I see that may help you improve your code.

### Add error checking

In your `changeTag` routine, a segfault can occur if there is no file. Add this just after the `FileRef` line:

```
if(!file.isNull() && file.tag()) {
```

### Separate concerns

The code would be a little more clear if the `changeTag` routine was split into two parts. In particular, one could extract artist and title, and the other could apply those. It may also be reasonable to make `extractFiles` return the vector of errors rather than having it emit those errors to `std::cout`.  The calling program might be able to do something different with those, such as if it were a GUI.

### Use command line parameters

Instead of prompting for a directory name, it would be better to have that as a command line parameter.  That would also simplify the control structure of your program as mentioned in the next comment.

### Try to consolidate loop exit conditions at the top

Prefer a `for` loop with the actual exit condition to a `while(true)` loop.  Because the reader is forced to search for the loop terminating condition, it's more effort to understand the latter construct.  This code, for example could be structured like this:

```
int main() {
    std::string dir;
    std::cout << "Directory: Enter 'x' to close: ";
    for (std::cin >> dir; dir != "x"; std::cin >> dir) {
        extractFiles(dir);
    }
}
```

This also eliminates a `break` statement.  A `break` can also contribute to difficulties understanding a loop because again, the programmer reading the code has to search for them.

### Consider the user

It might be nice to have an option for a "dry run" of the program.  That is, have it print what it *would* have done without actually altering any files.  This would help the user have confidence that the program was doing only and exactly what was intended.

Comment: in changeTag, I wanted to put the whole code inside a try catch so it will catch if no file is found. But I don't know what exception to catch because I really can't find any exceptions in the taglib docs, and I thought extractFiles' error checking is enough. I'm curious as to why you use an if statement for error checking?